# auto_arima returning the best model as SARIMAX even when time series is stationary and has no seasonal component in Python

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I have a time series dataset having frequency as daily. I have checked that my dataset is stationary using augmented dickey-fuller test.

After which, when i am trying to determine the values of p,d,q using:

```
from pmdarima import auto_arima
stepwise_fit = auto_arima(df2['Births'],start_p=0,max_p=6, start_q=0, max_q=3, seasonal=False,trace=True)
```

Moreover, I have mentioned seasonal=False in auto_arima argument, but when i did:

```
stepwise_fit.summary()
```

Its returning:

```
SARIMAX Results
Dep. Variable:  y   No. Observations:   365
Model:  SARIMAX(1, 1, 1)    Log Likelihood  -1226.077
Date:   Mon, 17 Feb 2020    AIC 2460.154
Time:   20:02:17    BIC 2475.743
Sample: 0   HQIC    2466.350
- 365       
Covariance Type:    opg     
             coef   std err   z     P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
intercept   0.0132  0.014   0.975   0.330   -0.013  0.040
ar.L1       0.1299  0.059   2.217   0.027   0.015   0.245
ma.L1      -0.9694  0.016   -62.235 0.000   -1.000  -0.939
sigma2      48.9989 3.432   14.279  0.000   42.273  55.725
Ljung-Box (Q):  36.69   Jarque-Bera (JB):   26.17
Prob(Q):        0.62    Prob(JB):   0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H): 0.97    Skew:   0.58
Prob(H) (two-sided):    0.85    Kurtosis:   3.62
```

We can see, its returning Model: SARIMAX(1, 1, 1). What can we infer from it? Any suggestion is helpful, or if i am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason its showing SARIMAX(1, 1, 1). It simply means ARIMA only because the format for SARIMAX is basically SARIMAX(p,d,q)*(P,D,Q) where P,D,Q are seasonal parameters, so, in our case SARIMAX(1,1,1)*(0,0,0) seasonal components are zero only.